# Como conectar um Banco do PostgreSQL no Visual Studio visual Studio Community?

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio

olá, recentemente venho tendo problemas para conectar ao meu banco de dados no Visual Studio, o banco é feito pelo PostgreSQL, entretanto não achei nem um conteúdo que me ajudasse a fazer o que eu queria, alguns pedem para estalar um Nugget do PostgreSQL, mas tento fazer o mesmo e não consigo acessar o banco pelo explorador SQL do Visual Studio.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer conectar e visualizar as tabelas do Postgres via VS Studio Community.

Não é possível sem plugins, sinceramente não acho que valha a pena também.

"mais leve" e extensível por acessar vários tipos de base de dados diferentes é instalar o VS Studio Code juntamente com a extensão do `[Weijan Chen][1]`